# how to install fact++ Plugin for protege and enable start Reasoner

Tags: protege4, fact++

hi i am new to protege .

i downloaded protege 4.0.2 and made an ontology in it but it seems like that i dont have any reasoner to check its consistency.

it is also showing a reasoner tab but after selecting fact++ i dont see any changes.

if i have not done it correctly then from where can i download fact++ or any other reasoner for protege and how can i install it.

i have browsed a lot but did not find a thing on how to install reasoner.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a newer version of Protege - at least 4.3.0.

In order to activate the reasoner you ned to select one and then choose 'Start reasoner', in the same menu.

To install new reasoners, you can use the plugin menu in the Protege interface, or you can download the reasoner plugin you want (typically distributed as a jar) and copy in inside the plugins folder that you can find in the Protege installation. Start Protege after the copy, and the reasoner should appear in the reasoner menu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Protege -> plugins -> and check if FactPlusPlus plug in is installed or not. if yes, then you will see the Fact++ Reasoner in Reasoner Menu.

[image]

if fact++ plugin is not installed, then follow the below steps.

1. click the checkbox on for "Automatically check for plug updates at start up"
2. Restart Protege
3. You will see the automatic update Window open on the restart shown below.
   select Fact++ plugin and install

[image]

4. Restart Protege
5. Go to Reasoner menu -> select Fact++ ->  it will enable start Reasoner option

[image]